# Как инициализировать атрибуты класса значением Promise функции

Tags: javascript, классы, promise

Помогите справиться со следующей проблемой:
Есть класс метод которого *Initialize()* вызывает Promise функцию результат которой я хочу записать в атрибуты класса

```
module.exports = class MyPokedex {
    constructor() {
        const Pokedex = require('pokedex-promise-v2');
        this._P = new Pokedex();
        this.total = 0;     // How many total pokemons
        this.names = [];    // Name
        this.promiseResolved = false;
    }

    async Initialize() {
        let interval = {
            limit: 1,
            offset: 0
        }
        const self = this;    

        self.promiseResolved = false;
        // Пытаюсь сделать await но эффекта нет ...
        await this._P.getPokemonsList(interval)
        .then( function(response) {
            self.total = response.count;
            for(let line of response.results)
                self.names.push(line.name);           
            self.promiseResolved = true;
        }, (err) => console.log("Промис выполнен с ошибкой", err));

        console.log('finished');
        console.log('this.total', this.total);
        console.log('this.names', this.names.length);
        console.log('this.promiseResolved', this.promiseResolved);
    }
}

// *** pdemo.js ***************************************

const MyPokedex = require('./pclass');
let myP = new MyPokedex();
console.log(myP.promiseResolved);
console.log('Main Initialize');
myP.Initialize();
console.log('Main Initialize finished');
// while (!myP.promiseResolved)
  console.log(myP.promiseResolved);
  console.log(myP.total);
```

При выполнении node pdemo в консоли вижу следующее:

```
C:\nodejs\MyPrj\mobx-master>node pdemo
false
Main Initialize
Main Initialize finished
false
0
finished
this.total 964
this.names 2
this.promiseResolved true
```

Получается что-то странное ?! Вроде бы await срабатывает, но почему тогда внутри pdemo.js значения атрибутов 0 и false (не инициализированы) ?

Comment: Очевидно, потому что перед console.log вы никак не дожидаетесь момента, когда асинхронный Initialize() закончит свою асинхронную работу и проставит атрибуты.

Comment: И как мне нужно это сделать ?

Comment: Асинхронные функции возвращают промис, который срабатывает, когда функция завершит свою асинхронную работу. Соответственно, вам нужно написать что-то вроде `myP.Initialize().then(() => { console.log('Main Initialize finished'); })` и уже внутри then обращаться к атрибутам

Comment: @andreymal, либо просто продолжить пользоваться async и await :)

Comment: если используешь await, то then особо не нужен

Comment: @Grundy но для этого придётся завернуть весь незавёрнутый код в асинхронную функцию

Comment: @Grundy А почему этот вопрос до сих пор не задубликачен? :)

Comment: @Yaant, с одной стороны лень, с другой не уверен каким именно закрыть :) можешь проголосовать за закрытие я добью :)